# Android not registering A and PTR records with DNS server

Tags: dns, dhcp, samsung-droid-charge

I have been running ISC BIND and DHCP servers on my private lan for quite some time now. Recently, I configured the two servers to enable Dynamic DNS updates to my private zone. It seems to be working, as a couple of laptops and my old phone (Motorola Droid, rooted with an older version of CyanogenMod) did register their A and PTR records with my DNS server.

However, my current phone (Samsung Charge, rooted with Eclipse ROM v2.0) is NOT registering with my DNS server. I have noticed that in my lease cache (excerpted below), my Charge doesn't have any of the DDNS related entries that the other leases do. I'm thinking that the Charge, for whatever reason, isn't passing it's hostname to the DHCP server. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to confirm this suspicion, much less correct the behavior if I'm right. Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Excerpt of /var/state/dhcp/dhcpd.leases:

```
# This is the lease for the Samsung Charge. It did NOT register with DNS.
lease 192.168.1.127 {
  starts 6 2012/05/19 01:10:38;
  ends 6 2012/05/19 01:20:38;
  cltt 6 2012/05/19 01:10:38;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 78:d6:f0:69:af:9f;
  uid "\001x\326\360i\257\237";
}

# This is the lease for my mother's laptop. It DID register with DNS.
lease 192.168.1.126 {
  starts 6 2012/05/19 01:10:45;
  ends 6 2012/05/19 01:20:45;
  cltt 6 2012/05/19 01:10:45;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 90:4c:e5:47:cf:ee;
  set ddns-rev-name = "126.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.";
  set ddns-txt = "0061e3886dfc34c99e5f945805f4197a39";
  set ddns-fwd-name = "hestia.[public name removed].dyndns.org";
  client-hostname "hestia";
}
```